# Auto Fit Row Height on Protected Worksheet WITH LINKED source content

Tags: excel, row, height

I have a protected worksheet which retrieves formatted data from a transactional system (SQL Server) to pre-populate a form.  One of the data elements that I'm pulling is an NVARCHAR(1000) field, so the potential exists for a lot of data, including the possibility of carriage returns.  The downloaded data comes to a hidden tab in a flat-file format, 1-row, 102 fields.  From there, the main "form" view is setup with links to the corresponding field in the hidden download tab.

For this one field, I would like the form to be able to auto-expand the Row Height on THIS ROW ONLY to accommodate whatever may be downloaded.  I have tried:

- setting the fields to Protection/Locked OFF
- Home / Cells / Format AutoFit Row Height
- Wrap Text

Trying to do this without having to invoke a macro or VBA if possible.  Appreciate any thoughts - am I missing something simple/obvious?